# Rails encode control characters and send over a socket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, bindata

Using [Eventmachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine) I have been able to build a simple client/server program that successfully sends data over a socket. But the server expects that data is a specific format.

In order to communicate with the server, the first step is to send a WAKEUP call and get acknowledgment. The server expects a 3 byte ID in the wakeup call. An example is provided in the documentation that shows the success scenario of sending the ID and receiving the ack.

The client should send the data is the following format:

```
<sy><sy><eq>111<et>
```

Within <> brackets is a non-printable ASCII character ( `<sy>` = ASCII 22 or Hex 0x16)

Here is some detail of the characters:

> `<sy>` = **ASCII:** 22, **Hex:** 0x16 , **Character:** ^V
>
> `<eq>` = **ASCII:** 5, **Hex:** 0x05 , **Character:** ^E
>
> `<et>` = **ASCII:** 4, **Hex:** 0x04 , **Character:** ^D

I'm using a gem [Bindata](https://github.com/dmendel/bindata) to represent the `<sy><sy><eq>111<et>` but don't know exactly which type to use. Can you provide a way to acheive this?

Comment: Can't you just send a string like `"\x16\x16\x05111\x04".force_encoding('binary')`?

Comment: There are several other combinations that I need to send that's why I used that Bindata gem to represent it properly instead of sending strings.

Comment: Why not JSON style with things like `\x16`?

Comment: @tadman can you give me an example?

Comment: Surely Bindata supports byte strings.